# Rails 2.3.11 -> 3.2.3 simple gsub with regex does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, gsub

I tried to upgrade my Rails 2.3.11 application to Rails 3.2.3, but this function in ApplicationHelper does not work properly anymore in the browser (in Rails console everything is fine):

```
def basic_markup(text)
  if text
    text.gsub!(/(\A|\s|\[|\()_(.+?)_/iu, '\1<em>\2</em>')
    text.gsub!(/(\A|\s|\[|\()#(.+?)([^&])#/iu, '\1<del>\2\3</del>')
    text.gsub!('->', '→')
    text.gsub!('<-', '←')
  end
  text
end

text = '#strikeout# normal _italic_'
puts basic_markup(text)
# Rails 2.3.11
# => "<del>strikeout</del> normal <em>italic</em>"
# Rails 3.2.3
# => "#strikeout# normal <em>italic</em>"
```

Sample on Rails 2.3.11: http://moly.hu/karcok/150362

The same on Rails 3.2.3: http://moly.hu:3000/karcok/150362

What's wrong?

Comment: maybe the text you are sending is being sanitised. try using text.html_safe to see if the del tag is being replaced with &gt; and &lt;

Comment: It does not seem like a sanitation problem, markup characters are appearing in the output.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't changed anything in the view that's calling `basic_markup(text)`? It might help to see a snippet of view code to see that there's nothing weird going on over there. The method itself seems to work properly.

Comment: Update to my comment above: I just tried creating a new rails 3.2.3 project, put that method in the `application_helper` and calling it from a view with the same text, and works just fine. I think you're missing something somewhere else.

Comment: Problem solved, maybe Rails' simple_format has changed between 2.3.11 and 3.2.3, but now it runs correctly. Thanks for the comments!

Comment: @Frost or NagyBence - If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Copying the answer from the comments in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter:

[Frost](https://stackoverflow.com/users/746882/frost) suggested an upgrade:

> Update to my comment above: I just tried creating a new rails 3.2.3 project, put that method in the `application_helper` and calling it from a view with the same text, and works just fine. I think you're missing something somewhere else.

[Nagy Bence](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1343619/nagy-bence) confirmed:

> Problem solved, maybe Rails' simple_format has changed between 2.3.11 and 3.2.3, but now it runs correctly. Thanks for the comments!